# how to execute a line of code only once inside of a loop?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, while-loop

beginner here, I'm trying to do a while true loop that reads a value of an integer in a game indefinitely. what I wanna do is, when that integer = x value, execute a certain code but only once.

I used this code

```
while (true)
{

    
    var value = swed.ReadInt(localplayer, offsets.health);


    if (value == 70)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }


}
```

the problem is, when the value is 70, it prints "hello" forever when I only want it to be printed once. keep in mind I want that value to be read indefinitely and print "hello" once when its 70 so I can't use break otherwise it would only work once. I tried to use for loop which printed that message once as I wanted it to, but it only works if that value is 70 to begin with. it doesn't read that value continuously like the while loop. so I guess I need to use a nested loop? I tried a lot of different things bot nothing has worked so far

Comment: you need to create a boolean flag 'hasExecuted' (or appropriate name). check and set it when you check and perform your condition

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I used break. whenever the value is 70 I want "hello" to be printed once. if I use the break it will only work once and when the value is 70 again nothing would happen

Comment: @Finn Please [edit] the question to clarify if you want it to happen multiple times or not

Comment: Do you want to break out of the while loop entirely after someone has entered 70 and you’ve replied hello?

Comment: Not entirely. the value keeps changing. so I need it to be read indefinitely. and when its 70 I always want it to print "hello" but only print it once. so I can't use break because if the value lets say changes to 80 then back to 70, nothing will be printed

Comment: Ok, to clarify; if the value is 70 twice in a row you want hello once. If the value changes to something else then back to 70 you want it to print hello again?

Comment: yes, and yes. it would be great. I've been trying to figure this out for a whole day and I couldn't. just to give you more details. I'm checking a health value in a game. it can change if the player is damaged. so the health value has to be read indefinitely. and whenever its 70 I want hello once. just using this silly example to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to print hello when the input value is 70 and not if the value doesn’t change but then again if it does change back to 70, then you could keep track of the previous value.

```
var previousValue = 0;
var currentValue = 0;

while (true)
{
  currentValue = swed.ReadInt(localPlayer, offsets.health);

  if (currentValue == 70 && previousValue != 70)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(“hello”);
  }

  previousValue = currentValue;
}
```

Not the most elegant of solutions but illustrates the basic idea. You can tidy up as required.

Comment: Thank you so much. this actually worked!

Comment: @Finn Good stuff. You could improve it by moving the if conditional logic to a method of its own (if the logic will be reused) and make the value 70 its own variable and reference it so if it changes, it changes in one place only but updates everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TP95, his/her code can be a little changed to support your issue:

```
var hasExecuted = false;
while (true)
{

    var value = swed.ReadInt(localplayer, offsets.health);

    if (value == 70 && !hasExecuted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
        hasExecuted = true;
    }
    if (value != 70 && hasExecuted)
    {
       hasExecuted = false;
    }
}
```

Sorry, that I wasn't able to comment on your answer.

Answer (score -1):

if the purpose of your question is to trigger something once the value reaches 70, you should instead have a listener on your attribute.

check the following example code assuming that it's being used in unity:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string myAttribute;
    
    public string MyAttribute
    {
        get { return myAttribute; }
        set
        {
            if (myAttribute != value)
            {
                myAttribute = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyAttribute));
            }
        }
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
        myObject.PropertyChanged += MyObject_PropertyChanged;
        
        // Change the attribute value to trigger the event
        myObject.MyAttribute = "New value";
    }
    
    private static void MyObject_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Function to be triggered when the attribute changes
        // Check if the property name is "MyAttribute"
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(MyAttribute))
        {
            // Get the new value of MyAttribute
            string newValue = MyAttribute;
        
            // Perform conditional logic based on the new value
            if (newValue == "SomeValue")
            {
                // Do something when the value is "SomeValue"
                Debug.Log("Property value is 'SomeValue'.");
            }
            else
            {
                // Do something else when the value is not "SomeValue"
                Debug.Log("Property value is not 'SomeValue'.");
            }
        }
    }
```